# pytest use data from one test as parameter to another test

Tags: pytest

I am wondering if it is possible to use data generated from one test as parameter to another test. In my case I need to modify variable (this is list) and it will be great if I can use this list as param (run as many tests as list have)

Here is code (it is not working, but maybe You can give me some hints)

```
import pytest


class TestCheck:

    x = [1, 4]


    @classmethod
    def setup_class(self):
        print('here setup')

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(self):
        print('here is finish')

    def test_5(self):
        self.x.append(6)
        assert 1 == 2

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("region", x)
    def test_6(self, region):
        assert region > 5, f"x: {self.x}"
```

Output:

```
FAILED sandbox_tests3.py::TestCheck::test_5 - assert 1 == 2
FAILED sandbox_tests3.py::TestCheck::test_6[1] - AssertionError: x: [1, 4, 6]
FAILED sandbox_tests3.py::TestCheck::test_6[4] - AssertionError: x: [1, 4, 6]
```

So it looks that in x there is good values, however in fixture new values are not visible.

I was also trying to use pytest_cases, but results are very similar.

Any help is appreciate

Comment: You should create the input list to every test, it is not a good practice to have dependency between tests because they wouldn't be unitary test.

Comment: It is complicated:) I'm aware that this is not a good approach, but I believe that in my case it is the best approach. What do You mean by "input list"?. I need to run test_5 as first (before test_6), because of output from test 5 gives me arguments needed by test 6. As I've written I can read this values (x) in test_6, but I'd like to use it as parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chaining tests and passing an object from one test to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238725/chaining-tests-and-passing-an-object-from-one-test-to-another)

Comment: @DevangSanghani, no it doesn't. I need to use results as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestParamPropagatable:

    DATA1 = None

    def test_fetch_data(self, request):
        cls = __class__
        cls.DATA1 = 'hello'


    DATA2 = None

    def test_fetch_data(self, request):
        cls = __class__
        cls.DATA2 = cls.DATA1 + ' world'
```

you may further simplify cls assigement (first line) with decorator or etc.